# pthread_create will terminate previous thread which has the same tid?

Tags: linux, multithreading

I found that in below codes, a thread is created each time when a new client is accepted. And in function pthread_client() there is no exit log. But it seems that no multi-threads are created by command `ps aux`

My understanding is that each time a new thread is created with same tid, the old thread which has the same tid will be killed automatically, is it right?
Thanks!

```
while(1){
    fd = accept(...);
    pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, (void *)pthread_client, (void *)arg);
    pthread_detach(tid1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My understanding is that each time a new thread is created with same tid, the old thread which has the same tid will be killed automatically, is it right? Thanks!

No, you are wrong!

From the manuals:

```
 int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                      void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

> Before returning, a successful call to pthread_create() stores the ID
>          of the new thread in the buffer pointed to by thread;

That means: In your variable `tid` by every call a *new* value will be stored. The old value will be overridden, simply it is nowhere used in the code anymore. So you get always a new thread but your code can not access the "older" threads later. But as you see, your code simply detaches from the currently new created thread so there is no need to process anything later.

The previous created threads simply continue. You can't kill an running thread with a call to `pthread_create`.